# Lenovo Wireless adapter cannot access network on Win 10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, lenovo-laptop

After Win 10 upgrade on one laptop and clean Win 10 installation on other Lenovo laptop, I am unable to connect to a home wireless router.

Wireless network is available and visible on both laptops, I am asked for a password and after that I receive a message Cant connect to this network.

Laptop is T440S, wireless adapters is Intel N-7260.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing Wi-Fi security from Wep to Wpa2 did the trick

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility, that the both Lenovo's have got on the Upgrade/Clean Install maybe even same "too new" WLAN-drivers in relation to the existing router. This could be checked with another/newer router. Another try could be "forgetting" the router's WLAN connection on both Lenovo's at -> Settings/Network/WLAN/Administer known networks, and then re-connecting giving the Network Security Key as a re-fresh.

Edit: OK, some more hints in here -> [Wifi network undetectable on a Lenovo G470](https://superuser.com/questions/338942/wifi-network-undetectable-on-a-lenovo-g470?rq=1)

Comment: @John OK, nice you found the exact point, and, thanks!